# Разбиение месяца по неделям в PHP

Tags: php, дата

Нужно вывести статистику по неделям. Для этого желателен массив с неделями по дням. Например возьмем текущий месяц (Декабрь)

```
1ая неделя - 01.12.2019 (Вс)
2ая неделя - с 02.12.2019 (Пн) по 08.12.2019 (Вс)
3ая неделя - с 9.12.2019 (Пн) по 15.12.2019 (Вс)
4ая неделя - с 16.12.2019 (Пн) по 22.12.2019 (Вс)
5ая неделя - с 23.12.2019 (Пн) по 29.12.2019 (Вс)
6ая неделя - с 30.12.2019 (Пн) по 31.12.2019 (Вт)
```

И сам массив:

```
[0] = [1];
[1] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
[2] = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
[3] = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22];
[4] = [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29];
[5] = [30, 31];
```

С переходом на след месяц

1ая неделя - с 1.01.2019 (Ср) по 5.01.2019 (Вс)
и тд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать примерно следующую функцию, которая будет генерировать необходимый двумерный массив, элементами которого являются недели месяца.

```
function getWeeksOfMonth(string $data): array
{
    $arrayOfWeeks = [];

    $period = new DatePeriod(
        DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-n-d', $data),
        new DateInterval('P1D'),
        DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-n-d', $data)->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))
    );

    foreach ($period as $weeks) {
        $arrayOfWeeks[$weeks->format('W')][] = $weeks;
    }

    $arrOfDays = function($stack): array {
        foreach ($stack as $w => $date) {
            $base[] = range($date[0]->format('d'), $date[count($date)-1]->format('d'));
        }
        return $base;
    };

    return $arrOfDays($arrayOfWeeks);
}
```

Проверяем функцию и смотрит конечный результат:

```
foreach (getWeeksOfMonth('2019-12-01') as $k => $v) echo join(', ', $v) . PHP_EOL;

// 1
// 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
// 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
// 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22
// 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
// 30, 31
```

https://3v4l.org/cgnc5

Думаю дальше не будет проблемой самостоятельно привести результат в нужный вид.

Answer (score 2):

Тут основная проблема с локализацией даты. В зависимости от локали будут печататься дни не дели на языке локали.

Вот пример

```
$dateStart="01 december 2019";
$dt= strtotime( $dateStart);
$currdt=$dt;
$nextmonth=strtotime($dateStart."+1 month"."-1 day");
$i=0;
do 
{
    $weekday= (6+date("w",$currdt))%7;
    $endday=abs($weekday-6);
    $startarr[$i]=$currdt;
    $endarr[$i]=strtotime(date("d-m-Y",$currdt)."+$endday day");
    if ($endarr[$i]>=$nextmonth){
        $endarr[$i]=$nextmonth;
    }
    $currdt=strtotime(date("d-m-Y",$endarr[$i])."+1 day");

    $nameOfStartDay = date('D', $startarr[$i]);
    $nameOfEndDay = date('D', $endarr[$i]);
    print(($i+1)."-ая неделя - c ". date("d.m.Y",$startarr[$i])."(".$nameOfStartDay.") по ". date("d.m.Y",$endarr[$i])."(".$nameOfEndDay.")\n");
     $i++;

}while($endarr[$i-1]<$nextmonth);
```

Вывод

```
1-ая неделя - c 01.12.2019(Sun) по 01.12.2019(Sun)
2-ая неделя - c 02.12.2019(Mon) по 08.12.2019(Sun)
3-ая неделя - c 09.12.2019(Mon) по 15.12.2019(Sun)
4-ая неделя - c 16.12.2019(Mon) по 22.12.2019(Sun)
5-ая неделя - c 23.12.2019(Mon) по 29.12.2019(Sun)
6-ая неделя - c 30.12.2019(Mon) по 31.12.2019(Tue)
```

Answer (score 0):

В финансовой системе, конец недели - это утро следующего понедельника, вот решение:

```
function monthToWeeks($month, $year)
{
    $lastDay = date('d.m.Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year));
    $weeks = [date('d.m.Y', mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year))];
    for ($i = 2; $i < date('t'); $i++) {
        $t = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $year);
        if (date('N', $t) == 1) {
            array_push($weeks, date('d.m.Y', $t));
        }
    }
    array_push($weeks, $lastDay);
    $countOfWeeks = count($weeks) - 1;
    $i = 0;
    echo 'In ' . date('F Y', mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year)) . ' we have ' . 
$countOfWeeks . ' weeks:<br><br>';
    while ($i < $countOfWeeks) {
        echo $i+1 . ' week - from ' . $weeks[$i] . ' to ' . $weeks[$i+1] . '<br>';
        $i++;
    }
}
monthToWeeks(12, 2019);

Output:
In December 2019 we have 6 weeks:

1 week - from 01.12.2019 to 02.12.2019
2 week - from 02.12.2019 to 09.12.2019
3 week - from 09.12.2019 to 16.12.2019
4 week - from 16.12.2019 to 23.12.2019
5 week - from 23.12.2019 to 30.12.2019
6 week - from 30.12.2019 to 01.01.2020
```